# How can i get WOEID by Latitude and longitude?

Tags: php, geocoding, yahoo

In my application, i have only the Latitude and longitude of the current position. How can i get WOEID by Latitude and longitude ?

Comment: Have you used [WOEID Lookup](http://woeid.rosselliot.co.nz/) and [Yahoo! WOEID](http://developer.yahoo.com/geo/geoplanet/guide/concepts.html)?

Comment: I want to fetch WOEID of the user's location who uses my website and forecast the local weather details on web page I have fetched local latitude and longitude but can't getting WOEID

Answer (score 6):

A YQL query will let you retrieve WOEID information based on latitude and longitude; for example:

http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20geo.placefinder%20where%20text%3D"37.416275%2C-122.025092"%20and%20gflags%3D"R"

See http://developer.yahoo.com/boss/geo/docs/free_YQL.html for their documentation.